# Class "XX" can not have multiple base classes

Tags: c#

I don't know whether it it silly to ask this question, but it stroked suddenly in my mind.

Since we already know any class can not have multiple base classes and we also know all the classes(types) is ultimately derived from `System.Object`. So  deriving any class from another class has already two classes (base classes) let's say

```
Class B{...}
Class D : B {...}
```

So conceptually `Class D` is derived from two different base classes first `D` and second `System.Object`.

Can't we say this assumption(classes can't have multiple base classes) failing wrong in every derived context or we need any other understanding to know this concept.

Comment: Well obviously, no.

Comment: No  D base object is in reality B base object and so on.

Comment: why can you explain

Comment: Yup it makes sense @Steve

Comment: *D -> B -> Object* is not the same thing as *D -> B and Object*

Comment: FYI There is nothing that says that multiple inheritance can't work, in fact many languages support multiple inheritance. It's just c# doesn't.

Comment: If you follow your reasoning then D derives from object and from B and B derives from object so D derives from 3 base classes. And if B derives from Z ? Do we have 5 bases?

Comment: No multiple inheritance means no deadly diamond of death!

Comment: Yup man I also know, I added C# tag, any way steve's answer is good.@Liam

Comment: Basically `object` is the default base class if one is not explicitly defined.

Comment: Yup @juharr it just sliped from my my mind , i also termed "ultimately" in my question, but still it sliped thanks anyway i got my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C#, derivation happens one class at the time

- `D` derives from `B`
- `B` derives from `Object`

`D` does not derive directly from `Object`, when `B` overrides some of the methods from `Object`, these changes still apply in `D`.

There are languages where multiple inheritance exists, like C++. There something like the following is possible:

- `D` derives from `B` and `A`

This is only possible in C# by using interfaces. You do not really inherit from multiple classes in C#, you inherit from one and implement interfaces when needed. If you want to have a class that inherits from multiple classes you need to use an interface if you want to share the public properties and methods, but you will have to reimplement them by yourself.